Get Value From Query String (C#)
I have a query string that I want to get a value from. I want to extract a piece of text from the string and display it but I can't quite figure it out.
This is the query string:
utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Microsoft&gad_source
So I want to extract the piece of text after "utm_campaign" from the string and display it. In this case I will display the text "Microsoft".
How can I do this?
Any help is appreciated.

This string looks like a URL search/query. You could use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString to get a name value collection.

Be aware that HttpUtility.ParseQueryString will decode encoded stuff. That is presumable wanted but you should know. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters

As mentioned in one of the comments, using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString is a an appropriate solution as it is specifically made for parsing query strings.
You can use it like this:
var queryString = "utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Microsoft&gad_source=Chicken%20Giblets";
var queryStringData = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
var campaignValue = queryStringData.Get("utm_campaign");


Freexel: be aware that campaignValue could still be null, here (if "utm_campaign" happens to not be in the string).

This is pretty ugly but a very basic example using string.Split:
string a = "utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Microsoft&gad_source";

string[] pars = a.Split('&');
foreach (string par in pars)
{
    string[] parts = par.Split('=');
    if (parts[0] == "utm_campaign")
        return parts[1];
}

This splits the string by "&" into sections of "name=value". Then splits those strings in the loop by "=" to separate the name from the value.

Be aware that HttpUtility.ParseQueryString will decode encoded stuff. ...., and this code does not do that....

It has a bug, though: if "utm_campaign" weren't contained, then this would throw an index out of bounds for the last item.

Note: very basic example - not intended as a final solution.
